# Debugging a Windows store app - error messages always show the same line number

Tags: javascript, error-handling, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've set up error logging on my windows store app, which reports the error message and the line number in the code.

I've been getting two error messages from the same line, line 301. The error messages are

`The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

`Access is denied.`

Based on the First error message I presume the error is with my autosave function, but without the line number I can't say where it's failing. Here's my autosave code

```
function autosave()
{
    if ((localSettings.values["useAutoSave"] == null || localSettings.values["useAutoSave"] == "true")) {
        editorContent = editor.textContent;
        var text_length = editorContent.length;
        if (editedSinceSave && text_length > 0) {
            localSettings.values["lastContent"] = text_length;
            setStatus("<span class='loader'></span>autosaving", 2000);
            writeTempFile();
        }
    }
    window.setTimeout(autosave, _autosave_timeout);
}


function writeTempFile()
{
    try{
        tempFolder.createFileAsync("tempFile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
            .then(function (theFile) {
                return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(theFile, editor.textContent);
            }).done(function () {
                localSettings.values["lastPos"] = _lastStartPos;
            });
    }
    catch (e) {
        // statements to handle any exceptions
        logError(e); // pass exception object to error handler
    }
}
```

Even we I move all my functions around and recompile my code, the error is always at line 301. I suspect that the errorline I'm seeing is actually from whatever underlying js files are used to run my app, but I don't know where to access them. How the hell do I debug this?

Comment: Have you checked that the file tempFile.txt is not open or it is being used somewhere or check its permission?

Comment: Yes. I should point out the autosave function works, and writes to tempFile correctly. Although it may be that 1 out of 10 times it fails. Still, I have a try catch around the write statement and it doesn't seem to do any good. The app exits whenever this error happens and I only find out about it later in the log

Comment: What's in the call stack when the error happens? I assume you're using Visual Studio to debug the application?

Comment: is it possible that writeTempFile is called while the previous call to the same, has not finished? if yes - that can be root cause.

Comment: its a possibility. writeTempFile happens every 60 seconds. It hardly takes 60 seconds to write a text file but windows may hold it open in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's not a capability that you have not declared. It doesn't look like your code is using anything special, but it's worth a try.